# Not able to fetch reports data : Getting "Could not deserialize ReportingRequest" error

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests, spotify-app

I am trying to get reports data from spotify ads api using python:

```
reports = requests.post('https://api-partner.spotify.com/ads/v1.3/adAccounts/8a578aa1-e36d-42da-8110-52914f99f907/report',headers=headers,data=data)
```

I keep on getting this error :

```
{"error":{"type":"ParsingError","message":"Request is invalid","errors":["Could not deserialize ReportingRequest"],"sp_trace_id":"89e3b470-6bdd-4e03-8903-d4e814e71164"}}
```

The header part is correct as it working with other api endpoints like 'get campaign data', but I am suspecting the error is because of the 'data' part which is given by:

```
data = {
    "filters": {
    "campaign_ids": [
      "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
    ],
    "ad_set_ids": [
      "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
    ],
    "ad_ids": [
      "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
    ],
    "advertiser_ids": [
      "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
    ],
    "country_isos": [
      "string"
    ],
    "region_ids": [
      0
    ],
    "dma_ids": [
      0
    ],
    "platforms": "IOS",
    "campaign_statuses": "ACTIVE",
    "ad_set_statuses": "ACTIVE",
    "ad_set_start_dates": [
      "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"
    ],
    "ad_set_end_dates": [
      "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"
    ],
    "cost_type_filters": "CPCL",
    "report_datetime_range": {
      "report_start": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
      "report_end": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"
    }
  },
  "dimensions": "CAMPAIGN",
  "fields": "CLICKS",
  "organization_ids": [
    "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
  ],
  "ad_account_ids": [
    "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
  ],
  "continuation_token": "string",
  "page_size": 0
}
```

I tried using the curl command instead of python but still get the same error in the terminal :

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api-partner.spotify.com/ads/v1.3/report \
  --header 'Authorization: ' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "filters": {
    "campaign_ids": [
      "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
    ],
    "ad_set_ids": [
      "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
    ],
    "ad_ids": [
      "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
    ],
    "advertiser_ids": [
      "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
    ],
    "country_isos": [
      "string"
    ],
    "region_ids": [
      0
    ],
    "dma_ids": [
      0
    ],
    "platforms": "IOS",
    "campaign_statuses": "ACTIVE",
    "ad_set_statuses": "ACTIVE",
    "ad_set_start_dates": [
      "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"
    ],
    "ad_set_end_dates": [
      "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"
    ],
    "cost_type_filters": "CPCL",
    "report_datetime_range": {
      "report_start": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
      "report_end": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"
    }
  },
  "dimensions": "CAMPAIGN",
  "fields": "CLICKS",
  "organization_ids": [
    "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
  ],
  "ad_account_ids": [
    "497f6eca-6276-4993-bfeb-53cbbbba6f08"
  ],
  "continuation_token": "string",
  "page_size": 0
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the response when I passed the data in the following form:

```
data = {
   "dimensions": [
"COST_TYPE"
],
"fields": [
"CLICKS",
"COMPLETES",
"COMPLETION_RATE",
"CONVERSION_RATE",
"CTR",
"ECPCL",
"ECPM",
"ERRORS",
"FETCHES",
"FETCH_REACH",
"FIRST_QUARTILES",
"IMPRESSIONS",
"INTENT_RATE",
"LISTENERS",
"MIDPOINTS",
"NEW_LISTENERS",
"NEW_LISTENER_CONVERSION_RATE",
"NEW_LISTENER_STREAMS",
"OFF_SPOTIFY_IMPRESSIONS",
"PAID_LISTENS",
"PAID_LISTEN_FREQ",
"PAID_LISTEN_REACH",
"RENDER_RATIO",
"SERVES",
"SERVE_FREQ",
"SERVE_REACH",
"SKIPS",
"SPEND",
"STARTS",
"STREAMS",
"STREAMS_PER_NEW_LISTENER",
"STREAMS_PER_USER",
"THIRD_QUARTILES"
],
"filters": {


"ad_ids": [
      "5e30eed4-a4fe-4f8e-854c-33b438ab11b6"
    ],
"report_datetime_range": {
      "report_start": "2022-07-13T00:00:00Z",
      "report_end": "2022-07-16T23:00:00Z"
    }


},
}
```

The issue seemed to be in the report_start and report end dates.
According to the documentation, the minutes and seconds have to be passed as 00:00 as shown above